# Unauthorized Error When Trying to Create an Organization with InfluxDB CLI

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I have configured the `InfluxDB CLI` with the following configuration:

```
Active  Name                URL                     Org
*       cryptoGraphConfig   http://localhost:8086   cryptoGraph
```

I set up this configuration using the command:

```
influx config create -a -n cryptoGraphConfig -u http://localhost:8086 -o cryptoGraph -t 9H_567TJnINhmEpUq7k5dwJn53nP6__BGQydxWeuiAHB_VIS8JzHhww6gTrwwmxZhuuRoOswcudSRabs7ROlMg==
```

However, when I attempt to create a new organization using the `CLI`, I encounter the following error:

`Error: failed to create org "somename": 401 Unauthorized: write:orgs is unauthorized`

Despite having what seems to be a correctly configured CLI, I'm unable to create an organization. Can anyone help me identify and resolve this issue?